# Validating Data in a Text Box C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am making an application that Calculates a city's Population Increase or Decrease Percent. So you type a certain City and type in a certain State in their own text boxes and then you type in a beginning population in a 3rd textbox and an ending population in a 4th textbox, then hit calculate and it will display a increase or decrease based on the population data you entered.

Now I validated the numbers for the population so that whenever a non numeric value is entered in the population text boxes, a message box will be displayed telling the user to enter in numeric data.

I just cant figure out how to do the same with the city and state data. If somebody entered in a number in the city or state text box, how do I validate words?

Whenever a number is entered in either the city or state text box, how can I display a message box saying "Invalid Format"?

This is my Code

```
//Create a double for city
double dblCity;

//Create a Double for state
double dblState;

//Validate City
if (double.TryParse(txtCity.Text, out dblCity))
{
    //Validate State
    if (double.TryParse(txtState.Text, out dblState))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        //Display an error message for the textbox
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for State.");

        txtState.Focus();
        txtState.SelectAll();
    }
}
else
{
    //Display an error message for the textbox
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for City.");

    txtCity.Focus();
    txtCity.SelectAll();
}
```

It validates the City and State Text boxes to numeric values and anything else is invalid but I am trying to make it so when any numeric values are entered in the City or State Text Boxes it will be invalid. Only Words allowed in the City and State textboxes

Comment: Pls format your text a little bit.

Comment: How do you *currently* validate the input?  What logic do you want to define for this validation?  What if a city *does* have a number?  What specifically do you consider a "valid" city name?  Is "fcJJ-GHidF" a valid city name?

Comment: Well if you can validate numbers OK - why not use the same code to validate the text - if it passes the number validation then it is an error

Comment: So you can validate if a string is numeric, so whats the issue of just simply stating ``ValidNumeric(str) == false`` which means its a non-numeric string?

Comment: Can you share the code which apply validation on the textboxes?

Comment: Is this Winforms or WPF?

Comment: This is a WPF and i just updated my question with the code included

Comment: @E.Mules: I don't understand the logic you're implementing here... When you do this: `if (double.TryParse(txtCity.Text, out dblCity))` - You're saying that if the result is *false* (that is, if the input is *not numeric*), then the input is invalid?  This means that you're only accepting *numeric* input in those fields?  Are you just looking to swap your `if` and `else` blocks?

Comment: Just move your code from the ``else`` to the ``if`` and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

If it is imperative that you have correct State / City entries, then you are best to provide drop-down lists rather than a text box.
You'll need to populate the lists.
I've never had to work with this data set, but a quick internet search will identify some resources where you can download such a list.
You may or may not need to pay for the privilege of downloading such a list - and this may or may not have a bearing on the completeness and accuracy of the list.

Possible resources (I haven't checked them) include:

https://github.com/grammakov/USA-cities-and-states
https://www.uscitieslist.org
http://www.citygridmedia.com/developer/blog/csv-download-of-cities-in-the-us-by-state

Comment: upvote for the ``may or may not`` parts :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all of your validation in one spot, try something like this:

Create a "TextChanged" handler in your XAML for the City textbox and the State Textbox.

In the code-behind, your handler should look something like:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This textbox accepts only alphabetical characters");
        textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is going to invalidate a lot of actual cities.  And some actual states.

Comment: @Clay07g This works now, so what I also want to do is limit the State text box to have a maximum amount of only 2 letters allowed to be typed into the text box and that they can only be capital letters?

Comment: @David I'm not suggesting a strict copy-paste. I would assume he would also modify the expression to allow special characters that pertain to his potential audience.